# What causes the unpickling error in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently getting an unpickling error for loading a gz file using the numpy load function. I'm not sure what's causing this. Could offer some suggestions. I'm not sure if the data inside the file might be the problem.

```
 import numpy as np
 import gzip
 import io
 import pickle


 n = np.load("proteins1.npy.gz",mmap_mode='r')
 print(n)
```

Here is the error:

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Aivan Francisco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    412             try:
--> 413                 return pickle.load(fid, **pickle_kwargs)
    414             except:
```

UnpicklingError:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-1-b9f88486c866> in <module>()
      7 #file_name = open("proteins1.npy.gz","r")
      8
```

---->     9 n = np.load("proteins1.npy.gz",mmap_mode='r')
          10 print(n)
          11

```
 C:\Users\Aivan Francisco\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
     414             except:
     415                 raise IOError(
 --> 416                     "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" %   repr(file))
    417     finally:
    418         if own_fid:

 OSError: Failed to interpret file 'proteins1.npy.gz' as a pickle
```

Comment: Why are you using `mmap_mode='r'`?  What happens if you remove that argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `numpy.load` expects to read an uncompressed `*.npy` file, not a gzipped `*.npy.gz` file.  Try uncompressing the file first before loading it.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Yeah for some reason some of my friends didn't need to unzip it, but it just so happened that I needed to.